# ping some host failed on my ubuntu but ping the host in my openwrt router success

Tags: ubuntu, router

sudo route del default
sudo route add default gw 192.168.2.1
It can ping the host as normal.

Did I should write a crontab or something else like change the system setting? Or Is the sock used too many?

NOTE: I use this ubuntu as a crawler.

Is it too many SYN ?

Comment: this is question [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246211/ping-some-host- failed-on-my-ubuntu-but-ping-the-host-in-my-openwrt-router-succes)

Comment: Hi tink, it looks like your question was closed [on the unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246211/ping-some-host-failed-on-my-ubuntu-but-ping-the-host-in-my-openwrt-router-succes) for being unclear. It's not a programming question so it's not on-topic on Stack Overflow unfortunately. My recommendation would be to edit your question on the unix stack exchange to add more details so that they will be able to better help you over there.

Answer (score 0):

It's the route-cache

I use static IP with gateway 192.168.4.1
but the router crash,I manually add the route

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.4.3
```